# Split list into sub-lists based on attribute value

Tags: python, list

I have an array of objects that have a `suit` attribute, and I want to split into sub arrays based on which suit the object has.  I currently am using this:

```
    for c in cards:
        if c.suit.value == 0:
            spades.append(c)
        elif c.suit.value == 1:
            diamonds.append(c)
        elif c.suit.value == 2:
            clubs.append(c)
        else:
            hearts.append(c)
```

I have tried to use `itertools.groupby` as follows:

```
suits = [list(g) for g in intertools.groupby(cards, lambda x: x.suit.value)]
```

But this just yields:

```
[[3, <itertools._grouper object at 0x000000000296B2E8>], ...]
```

My first approach works, I just imagine there is a simple pythonic one liner that accomplishes what I need.

Comment: `groupby` works in "bursts". It will create lists for every sequence of spades. So it can yield `[[3, [c1, c2]], [1, [c3], [2, [c4, c5, c6]], [3, [c7]]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although it is not a one-liner, by using a list, we make it more elegant:

```
spades, diamonds, clubs, hearts = collcard = [[] for _ in range(4)]

for c in cards:
    collcard[c.suit.value].append(c)
```

Here we thus initialize a list with four empty sublists, then we append the card `c` to the list with index `c.suit.value`.

We use iterable unpacking to assign the first element to `spades`, the second to `diamonds`, etc.

The advantage is that we avoid sorting (which works in *O(n log n)*). So this algorithm has time complexity *O(n)* (given the amortized cost of list appending is *O(1)*).

Although oneliners are usually elegant, one should not put to much effort in writing these, since oneliners can be harder to understand, or have significant impact with respect to performance.

Comment: not a one-liner isn't an issue here. As trying to create a one-liner just kills performance. yeah, just like your last edit is saying. Got that one from Martijn, must be true :)

Comment: also nice _not_ using any dictionary or collections, or stuff :)

Comment: I really like this, also avoiding sorting is great! Thanks so much!

Comment: didn't you mean... for **c in** cards: ... ;)

Answer (score 9):

When iterated upon, `itertools.groupby` yields `tuple` objects: the key, and an iterable of the grouped values (allowing lazy evaluation of the data).

You just converted the `tuple` to a `list`, which isn't very useful.

Instead, you need to drop the key (for instance by unpacking it to `_`, pythonic way of telling that you're not using it) and force iteration on the values:

```
[list(g) for _,g in itertools.groupby(cards, lambda x: x.suit.value)]
```

now if you want to group *and* sort, it's not very efficient to pass `sorted(cards)` to `groupby` just for the pleasure to create a one-liner (one-liners are nice, but I prefer fast programs). Your approach works, or you can also use `collections.defaultdict`, and even name the dict with the proper color using an indirection, for instance like this:

```
import collections

cards = collections.defaultdict(list)
colors = ["spades","diamonds","clubs","hearts"]

for c in cards:
    cards[colors[c.suit.value]].append(c)
```

Comment: This does remove the tuple, however, as Willem Van Onsem noted above, this groups in bursts, and I only want at most 4 sub lists, one for each suit.  The list is not necessarily ordered by suit.  Is there a way to account for this using `groupby`?  Or is sorting by suit the way around this?

Comment: sorting works, but hell it's slow behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of the cards deck you can do something like this, considering is a 40 cards deck:

```
allcards = sorted(cards, key=lambda x: x.suit.value)
spades, diamonds, clubs, hearts =  map(lambda x: allcards[x:x+10], range(0,40,10))
```

Basiclly you get a sorted version of the deck, and take it in chuncks corresponding to the suits size. From spades to heards if they map from lower to higher index.